# How to Retain the max in each row , and all other numbers to 0

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to retain the maximum value in each row and change all the others to zero,
like this

```
a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8])
should be 
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,0]
```

So far I have been able to turn the maximum value to 1 and all the other values to zero.

```
a = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8]])
b = np.zeros_like(a)
b[np.arange(len(a)), a.argmax(1)] = 1
b
```

How can I retain the original value ?
I thought of multiplying the b with a , that could probably solve it. But surely there must be a simpler way.

Comment: Why have you used double square brackets to create the array `a` ?

Comment: ```(a.max() == a) * a``` should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use `numpy.where` for this task

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8]])
b = np.where(a==np.max(a), a, 0)
print(b)
```

output

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 9 0]]
```

Explanation: This does create `numpy.array` with same shape as `a` and corresponding values from `a` where condition is meet and `0` in all other places.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new array with only zeroes, replace index with max with the max value:

```
a = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8]])

a_empty = np.zeros_like(a)
a_empty[0][a.argmax(1)] = max(a[0])
```

Returns:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0]])
```

Note that

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
b = np.zeros_like(a)
b[np.where(a==np.max(a))] = np.max(a)
```

Looking at what you've tried, I am guessing you have initialised the initial array `a` incorrectly, and then used the argmax() as a 2-D array, if the array `a` was initialised incorrectly as I'm assuming, then your code should work like this:

```
a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8])

b = np.zeros_like(a)
b[np.argmax(a)] = np.max(a)
```